# Send smtp mail through c# windows forms?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send an email through c# windows forms, but it gives me an "5.5.1 Authentication Required" error:

[image: 5.5.1 Authentication Required]

Here is my code:

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("my@gmail.com", "my@gmail.com", "test", "Dette er en test");
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

                client.Port = 587;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my@gmail.com", "mypassword");

                client.EnableSsl = true;

                client.Send(mail);
                MessageBox.Show("Mail afsendt!", "Virkede!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
          catch (Exception ex)
            {

              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

I'm using the correct gmail address and password but it doesn't work!
Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

**Add This Line in ur code:**

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

Refernce:[UsedefaultCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx)

**or**

Your system share  multiple ip network then contact ur administrator and if u are using two step verification code in ur gmail please remove it.

Comment: if u are using two step verification code in ur gmail please remove it.

Comment: when u login ur gmail account its going directly into ur inbox or any other google password(two step verification code) will ask.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I had to change a security setting in gmail.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270?hl=en